# how to get automator app to run a yarn command

Tags: macos

I'm setting up an automator run shell script to go to a specific folder on users machines and then **yarn run dev** but when it gets to the yarn part it can't find yarn.

> -line 1: yarn: command not found

If I use terminal then yarn will run fine. 
I have yarn installed -g which is in my NVM modules.

Here is my script in automator.

```
cd ~/Documents/myProject
yarn run dev
```

Also tired this setup: 
[image]

Comment: In Terminal, run `which yarn` to find the full path. Use that in your script.

Comment: How would I use that in my script ?

Comment: Just add it on the front `/usr/local/bin/yarn run dev` or whatever it is.

Comment: Thanks Mark I tried that but then i get env: node: no such file or directory.

Comment: I don't use `yarn` or `node`. When you login to your computer it runs a login profile or startup script, something like `$HOME/.profile`. When you run Automator, it doesn't do that, so your PATH and any environment variables that are normally set in your Terminal are not set. That is why you needed to add the full path to `yarn`. There must be some othef `node/yarn` related stuff in your login profile that you need to ensure is set up when you run shell scripts in Automator. Sorry I can't be more specific.

Comment: Thanks Mark for all your help so far. hopefully someone else can fill in more of the blanks here.

Comment: It looks like it can't find `node` now. So, use this to find where `node` is `which node`. If it says `/some/path/to/node` add a line at the start if your script with `export PATH=$PATH:/some/path/to` Also add another colon and the path to the directory containing `yarn`.

Comment: I tried this but still the same message. export PATH=$PATH:/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin/node
cd ~/Documents/myProject
/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin/yarn yarn dev

Comment: I also tried export PATH=$PATH:/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin/node:/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin/yarn

Comment: Updated my post with what I used above showing screen shot

Comment: No, you should put the path of the directory **that contains** `node` not the path to `node` itself. Likewise for `yarn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/me/.nvm/versions/node/v10.16.3/bin
cd ~/Documents/myProject
yarn run dev
```

The first line tells `bash` where to look for programs, such as `yarn` and `node`.

Comment: Works thank you for that. Shame you can't pass variables into automator so you could change the node path per users machine.